# identify and delete all x64 architecture files

Tags: linux, bash, sed, objdump, rm

I have a folder with many .a and .o libraries for i386 and x64
I want to find and remove all the x64 libraries?
I know objdump can help but I don't know how to use it (maybe using a bash script with 'find' or 'sed') to make a list of the files and remove them.

Comment: You can use [file](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file) to find out whether a .o file is i386 or x86-64.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following script (it runs from the same folder with the libraries). I suggest you replace the "rm -f" with an echo first, to check the list of files to be deleted.

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *; do
   fileInfo=$(file $f)

   echo $fileInfo | grep -q "ELF 64-bit"
   exitCode=$?
   if [ $exitCode -eq 0 ]; then
      rm -f "$f"
   fi
done
```